# Querying to Oracle DB through JDBC gives null while direct query gives the output

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jdbc

I have a sql query which when I manually sends to an Oracle DB through SQLDeveloper Application gets me the output I want. But the same query returns nothing while I try to connect and query through JDBC driver why this is happening so. Please help me.

**code:**

```
String sql = "select * from tablename where id='" + id + "' AND case_id = '" + case_id + "'";

stmt = con.createStatement();
rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
System.out.println(sql);
System.out.println("next = " + rs.next());
```

**output:**

```
select * from tablename where id='1' AND case_id = '1000'
next = false
```

Both connections (JDBC and SQLDeveloper) are using same username and password. So no issue of privilege or security i think.

Comment: what are the column types?

Comment: have you tried putting value of id and case_id in code, directly?

Comment: i have executed the output sql that was printed by the `System.out.println(sql);` line and i got the output

Comment: You may also want to do query logging in the database to see the query that the application runs.

Comment: @BevynQ : `id` is of type `number` and `case_id` is `varchar2(20 Byte)`

Comment: @Romski : i used `System.out.println(sql);` to get the query generated. How else can I do a query logging?

Comment: `System.out.println(sql);` shows you the statement in your Java application, not necessarily the query as received by the database. You can turn on query logging in Oracle to see the query it is running and see if it is what you expected. How you do this depends on your version of Oracle, but Google will help

Comment: I cannot replicate your problem can you try `select * from tablename where id='1'`

Comment: below answer helped me, anyways thanks to all

Comment: plz vote up the question if u feel it will be helpful to others in future :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to pass the "id" as a number. As you are passing the ID as String, the JDBC driver will convert it to CHAR, VARCHAR, or LONGVARCHAR.

```
String sql = "select * from tablename where id=" + id + " AND case_id = '" + case_id + "'";
```

Resulting string:

```
select * from tablename where id=1 AND case_id = '1000'
```

Consider to use PreparedStatement with bind parameters, to avoid sql injection:

```
String sql = "select * from tablename where id = ? AND case_id = ?";

PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
ps.setInt(1, 1);
ps.setString(2, "1000");

ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
```

References:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jdbc/getstart/mapping.html
 http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html